# Monotonically decreasing sequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $(a_n),(b_n)$ be positive sequences such that $(a_n)$ decreases to $0$, monotonically.

If lim$_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}=1$, does it imply that $(b_n)$ decreases to $0$ monotonically?

Answer (score 4):

Try $a_n = 1/n$ and $b_n = a_n + (-1)^n/n^{3/2}$.